# Unable read response error

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm connecting eclipse to neo4j.. And I have 10k values and for small values its working fine.. For 10k values I'm getting this error,

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unable to read
>   response from server: Expected a string, but got: 0x1

Comment: Do you have Hexadecimal numbers in your data??

Comment: No there is no hexadecimal value

Comment: It clearly says that this is not a String and your code is reading a none String. You will find this when you debug the exact row.

Comment: ok. Is there any limitation in number of nodes and relationship creation in neo4j through java code ??